# How to run multiple queries against SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, exception

I have read and implemented several different versions of Microsofts suggested methods for querying a SQL Server database. In all that I have read, each query is surrounded by a using statement, e.g. In some method `DoQuery`:

```
List<List<string>> DoQuery(string cStr, string query)  
{
    using(SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cStr)) 
    {
        c.Open();

        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, c)) 
        {
            using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
            {
                while (reader.Read() ) 
                {
                     ...
                     //read columns and put into list to return
                }

           // close all of the using blocks
           }
        }
    }

    // return the list of rows containing the list of column values.
}
```

I need to run this code several hundreds of times for different query strings against the same database. It seems that creating a new connection each time would be inefficient and dropping it each time wasteful.

How should I structure this so that it is efficient? When I tried not using a using block and passing the connection into the `DoQuery` method, I got messages about the connection had not been closed. If I closed it after the query, then I got messages about it wasn't open.

I'm also trying to improve this because I keep getting somewhat random

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation on non-blocking socket would block.

I'm the only user of the database at this time and I'm not doing anything in multiple threads or async, etc. Just looping through query strings and running `DoQuery` on them.

Could my structure be part of that problem, i.e. not releasing the resources fast enough and thereby seeing the connection blocked?

I'm stuck here on efficiency and this blocking problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SqlConnection` is *not* a physical connection, thanks to connection pooling. It's merely a handle to a physical connection in the connection pool, which is reset when you acquire it. Reusing an `SqlConnection` makes sense in some rare cases, but should not generally be done, because it invites problems with thread safety and error recovery. Don't worry about limiting the scope of `SqlConnections` to just one query -- that's more or less exactly the way it's intended to be used.

Comment: open the connection, declare the command, then execute your statements, and close the connection at the end. the connection itself is not expensive because it will be pooled anyway, but reusing an already initialized command can boost performance greatly, especially when the queries you execute are parametrized and lend themselves to execution plan reuse and optimization.

Comment: I understand part of what you're saying about the pooling, but am I limiting the scope of the connection in the above?

Comment: Why do you think it is inefficient?  Have you run some benchmark tests to prove that it could be better?

Comment: Yes, the code sample is the way that `SqlConnection` is intended to be used. If this gives you problems, what you should be looking is, basically, any part of your code except this part. For example, is `cStr` the exact same string every time? Connection pooling keys on the exact connection string used, so the slightest variation will cause a different physical connection to be made, which is generally not what you want.

Comment: The connection code is the same always.  I was told by a code reviewer that this was inefficient.  I'm trying to make sure I'm doing it right.  Could any of this produce the IO Exception?

Comment: If You are only worrying about the efficiency in above code, that code looks good to me. But If you run the same code 1000s of time, then you should be more worried about the SQL Query itself that you are expected to run so many times. You should implement indexes in your table, avoid using subqueries as much as you can. You can use indexed views... There's a tons of optimizations guide available if you search in the google itself once.

Comment: Can you post the couple of queries (if you have multiple) that you are expected to run using that method?

Comment: The I/O exception is a Windows socket operation producing a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error. This is not usual when communicating with SQL Server, no matter how you actually do it, and this code is itself not the problematic bit. Check things like "enterprise" software firewalls, missing updates or other things that could be interfering at the network level. Try the same code on another machine if possible. Your reviewer could be right or wrong about the efficiency of the queries themselves, but they're not correct if they implied that you should be reusing the `SqlConnection` instance.

Comment: Why dont you use linq?

Comment: Always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  That you are only passing an sql string tells me you aren't doing that.

Comment: Agree in principle. I create the queries programmatically and execute with no user input. Queries are different each time and efficiency normally obtained by creating a parameterized command and changing values doesn’t work here as column names, condition like IN or NOT IN, <, >, BETWEEN all change for each query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the query structure was fine and the queries were fine. The problem was that I had an ‘order by X desc’ on each query and that column was not indexed. This caused a full table scan to order the rows even if only returning 2. The table has about 3 million rows  and I thought it could handle that better than it does. It timed out with 360 second connection timeout!  I indexed the column and no more ‘blocking’ nonsense, which BTW, is a horrible message to return when it was actually a timeout. The queries now run fine if I index every column that appears in a where clause.